# label ylab in timeSeries::plot, type = 'o'

Tags: r, plot, time-series

How do I label the y-axis, using `timeSeries::plot`, with Greek letters? i.e. change SB, SP, etc. to \alpha, \beta etc., I'm am aware I need `expression()`, in some way. However I can't even get to the labels (I normally use ggplot2). Code below.

[image: plot]

```
# install.packages("xtable", dependencies = TRUE)
library("timeSeries")

## Load Swiss Pension Fund Benchmark Data -
   LPP <- LPP2005REC[1:12, 1:4]
   colnames(LPP) <- abbreviate(colnames(LPP), 2)
   finCenter(LPP) <- "GMT"

timeSeries::plot(LPP, type = "o")
```

It have been pointed out that the object structure, obtained with `str()`, is quite particular in `LPP` compared to say this object `z`

```
z <- ts(matrix(rnorm(300), 100, 3), start = c(1961, 1), frequency = 12)
plot(z)
```

If any one has an answer to both or any I would appreciate it. I realize I can convert the data and plot it with ggplot2, I have seen that here on SO, but I am interested in doing in directly on the `timeSeries` object `LPP` and the `stats`  (time-series object) `z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[ REVISION & Edited ]**
When `plot.type` is `"multiple"`, we can't define `ylab` directly. Both `plot(ts.obj)` (`S3` method) and `plot(timeSeries.obj)` (`S4` method) take `colnames(obj)` as `ylab`, and I don't know any methods of using Greek letters as colname. (The difference in structure mainly comes from the difference of `S3` and `S4`; `colnames(timeSeries.obj)` is equivalent to `timeSeries.obj@units`; the defaults is `Series i` and `TS.i`).

We can step in `ylab` using the arugument, `panel` (It wants a `function` and the default is `lines`). It is used in `for(i in 1:ncol(data))`. I couldn't give `panel.function` a suitable `"i"` (I guess it can in some way, but I didn't think up), so I got `"i"` using which col the data matches.

**for `timeSeries`**

```
ylabs <- expression(alpha, beta, gamma, delta)
row1 <- LPP[1,]

timeSeries.panel.f <- function(x, y, ...) {
  lines(x, y, ...)
  mtext(ylabs[which(row1 %in% y[1])], 2, line = 3) 
}

plot(LPP, panel = timeSeries.panel.f, type = "o", ann = F)
title("Title")
mtext("Time", 1, line = 3)

 ## If you aren't so concerned about warnings, here is more general.
 ## (Many functions read `...` and they return warnings).
timeSeries.panel.f2 <- function(x, y, ..., ylabs = ylabs, row1 = row1) {
  lines(x, y, ...)
  mtext(ylabs[which(row1 %in% y[1])], 2, line = 3) 
}

plot(LPP, panel = timeSeries.panel.f2, type = "o", ann = F, 
     ylabs = expression(alpha, beta, gamma, delta), row1 = LPP[1,])
title("Title")
mtext("Time", 1, line = 3)
```

**for `ts`**

```
ylabs <- expression(alpha, beta, gamma)
row1 <- z[1,]

ts.panel.f <- function(y, ...) {
  lines(y, ...)
  mtext(ylabs[which(row1 %in% y[1])], 2, line = 3) 
}

plot(z, panel = ts.panel.f, ann = F)
title("Title")
mtext("Time", 1, line = 3)
```

[image]

Of course you can archieve it using new functions made from the original (mostly the same as the original). I showed only the modified points.

**modified `plot(ts.obj)`** (made from `plot.ts`)

```
my.plot.ts <- function(~~~, my.ylab = NULL) {
   :
  nm <- my.ylab    # before: nm <- colnames(x)
   :
}

# use
my.plot.ts(z, my.ylab = expression(alpha, beta, gamma), type = "o")
```

**modified `plot(timeSeries.obj)`**

```
# made from `.plot.timeSeries`
my.plot.timeSeries <- function(~~~, my.ylab = NULL) {
   :
  my.plotTimeSeries(~~~, my.ylab = my.ylab)
}

# made from `timeSeries:::.plotTimeSeries`
my.plotTimeSeries <- function(~~~, my.ylab) {
   :
  nm <- my.ylab      # before: nm <- colnames(x)
   :
}

#use
my.plot.timeSeries(LPP, my.ylab = expression(alpha, beta, gamma, delta), type="o")
```